# Reasoning behind derivative of log function $\log_{a}x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I was told to convert the following function

$$\log_{a}x$$
into

$$\ln x / \ln a$$
which makes sense. However, I am unsure as to why this would become

$$\frac{1}{x} * \frac{1}{\ln a}$$
instead of the result of the quotient rule:

$$\left[\frac{1}{x}(\ln a) - \frac{1}{a}(\ln x)\right]/(\ln a)^2$$

Is there a logical reason for this exception to the quotient rule? Or is this one of those functions you just have to memorize?

Comment: $\ln a$ is a constant.

Comment: @player3236 that makes sense. So the denominator stays the same.

Comment: You can "force" the use of the quotient rule using $(\ln a)'=0$. The result would be the same, as expected.

Comment: @player3236 : The use of the notation "$(\ln a)'$ is treacherous.  By default a prime is a derivative with respect to whatever single independent variable appears in the enclosed expression.  The only variable in the enclosed expression is $a$, so be default, the notation says to differentiate with respect to $a$, which is not what is meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, $\ln a$ is a constant, so using the quotient rule wastes time.

However, math works, so let's apply the quotient rule:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \frac{\ln x}{\ln a} &= \frac{(\ln a)(1/x) - (\ln x)(0)}{(\ln a)^2}  \\
    &= \frac{1}{x \ln a}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Here, since $a$ is a constant, the rate of change of $a$ (and of $\ln a$) with respect to a change in $x$ is zero.

Comment: Thanks. I just learnt that the derivative of $lna$ is 0. lol